# Auto-incremented data from a databse in a MVC Form in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

How do I put auto-incremented data from a database into the Create Form of an HTML form on a MVC Web Application in Visual Studio 2017?

Comment: On a create new item form? You do not -- the database will provide the value.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. The Create function was my problem. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't have to specify this id in your form just delete it and your entity framework will recognize this one to send it to the database. In your model you just have to specify that is and id auto-generated here is an example of one of my models... ignore the foreign key

```
public partial class Permit
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Employee")]
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }

    [StringLength(1)]
    public string Shift { get; set; }

    [StringLength(150)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public DateTime FromDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime ToDate { get; set; }
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
}
```